# Defining the circular order in the unit circle of a RCF (Real Closed Field).

Tags: model-theory

Let $R$ be a monster model of $RCF$ and $G$ the unit circle.

I know that we can define an order $\leq$ in $R$. I was wondering if we could also define a circular order $c(x,y,z)$ in the unit circle.

I think it should be possible, I went through all the possible combinations for relative postions of three points $a,b,c\in G$  and whether they are $c$-related or not. The formula I get is quite messy and probably quite redundant. Is there any easier way?

Comment: RCF = ?...........

Comment: @JeanMarie Real closed field. Sorry for not adding it

Comment: Does it really need to be an order on the circle? If you just want to interpret the cyclic order you can interpret it on the line as well, using the usual order.

Comment: @MarkKamsma And there's a definable bijection between the circle (minus a point) and the line, by stereographic projection. Transporting along this bijection gives a definition of the circular order on the circle that may be more efficient than the definition the OP has in mind.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I didn't really have any property in mind that I wanted to proof, I was just wondering about an explicit formula. I guess interpretability is good enough for all the properties I could be interested. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes, that approach seems definitely more efficient than what I was trying . I will have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández From your reply I understand that you know how to do this now? If so, then you could answer your own question ;)